# SSH git ls-remote doesnt work but git clone does?

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh, bitbucket

Currently puzzling over a Jenkins config issue.. Jenkins gives me this message:

```
Failed to connect to repository : Command "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\git.exe ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org:myuser/myrepo.git HEAD" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: Permission denied (publickey). 
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've configured ssh access keys in BitBucket, added them to the SSH cache for the windows user that Jenkins apache tomcat runs under. BitBucket's server IPs (3 of them) are showing in c:\users\tomcat.ssh\known_hosts`

I've logged into windows as the tomcat user, started an admin command prompt.

```
git clone git@bitbucket.org:myuser/myrepo.git
  -->success

git ls-remote -h git@bitbucket.org:myuser/myrepo.git HEAD
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.

ssh git@bitbucket.org
  PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
  authenticated via a deploy key.    
  You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
  This deploy key has read access to the following repositories:
  myuser/myrepo: Jenkins -- host14+company@host14
  myuser/myotherrepo: Jenkins -- host14+company@host14
  myuser/myotherotherrepo: Jenkins -- host14+company@host14
  Connection to bitbucket.org closed.
```

I found a tip that setting `GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -vvv` would make ssh be more verbose. No kidding:

```
C:\Users\tomcat\.ssh>git.exe ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:myuser/myrepo.git HEAD
OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "bitbucket.org" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [18.205.93.0] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version conker_1.1.15-49a70a8 app-190
debug1: no match: conker_1.1.15-49a70a8 app-190
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from bitbucket.org
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-dss,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:zzXQOXSRBEiUtuE8AikJYKwbHaxvSc0ojez9YXaGp1A
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from bitbucket.org
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/known_hosts:4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 18.205.93.0
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_rsa (0x60005f7d0)
debug2: key: /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:mZ1jvX4FViaDuD2Yn3aXzuC/znai7pcymoJlYsHuu/U
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:mZ1jvX4FViaDuD2Yn3aXzuC/znai7pcymoJlYsHuu/U
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to bitbucket.org ([18.205.93.0]:22).
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x08
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending command: git-upload-pack 'myuser/myrepo.git'
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
debug3: fd 0 is not O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2704, received 1640 bytes, in 10.1 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 267.5, received 162.2
debug1: Exit status -1
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Irritatingly, I did absolutely nothing other than re-run it, and it worked out fine:

```
C:\Users\tomcat\.ssh>git.exe ls-remote git@bitbucket.org:myuser/myrepo.git HEAD
OpenSSH_7.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "bitbucket.org" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [18.205.93.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version conker_1.1.15-49a70a8 app-130
debug1: no match: conker_1.1.15-49a70a8 app-130
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from bitbucket.org
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-dss,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:zzXQOXSRBEiUtuE8AikJYKwbHaxvSc0ojez9YXaGp1A
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from bitbucket.org
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 18.205.93.2
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_rsa (0x60005f7d0)
debug2: key: /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_dsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_ecdsa (0x0)
debug2: key: /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_ed25519 (0x0)
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /c/Users/tomcat/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:mZ1jvX4FViaDuD2Yn3aXzuC/znai7pcymoJlYsHuu/U
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:mZ1jvX4FViaDuD2Yn3aXzuC/znai7pcymoJlYsHuu/U
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to bitbucket.org ([18.205.93.2]:22).
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x08
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending command: git-upload-pack 'myuser/myrepo.git'
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 32768
debug3: receive packet: type 99
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: read<=0 rfd 4 len 0
debug2: channel 0: read failed
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 0: send eof
debug3: send packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: input drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 4
debug3: receive packet: type 98
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 96
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug3: receive packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug3: channel 0: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug3: send packet: type 97
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

debug3: send packet: type 1
debug3: fd 0 is not O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 2752, received 7212 bytes, in 10.4 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 265.8, received 696.5
debug1: Exit status 0
6bb76d5e076fff8e4ac05706cd760b0af8d6b19f        HEAD
```

The only difference I see is the host I'm conencted to - bitbucket.org is a roundrobin of 3 IP address. All these IPs are in my known hosts file. It also seems to have two IPv6 addresses that are not in my known hosts

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

So.. I upgraded my git/ssh to 2.19.4 (latest as of the date of this post) and it all started working